# Digital Clock shows Chinese characters

Tags: clock

I am in Lubuntu 14.04 My digital clock is showing the day and date in Chinese characters. I was in Japan and am now in Malaysia. The time is correct.  How can I get them to change back into English?

Answer (score 4):

system settings →language support→regional formats→display numbers, dates and currency amounts in the usual format for:English

Comment: How do I get into System Settings on 14.04 ?

Comment: It's in the launcher which is on the left of Desktop and the logo of system settings looks like  a gear and a spanner.